# Change font color when value is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I have an HTML made from app-script. In my website, I have a table where the value in it is coming from the spreadsheet. If I update the spreadsheet it will automatically update the data in the HTML table without refreshing the page.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
setInterval (function(){
 let data1 = document.getElementById('data1');
 let data2 = document.getElementById('data2');
 let data3 = document.getElementById('data3');
 let data4 = document.getElementById('data4');
 let data5 = document.getElementById('data5');
 let data6 = document.getElementById('data6');
 let data7 = document.getElementById('data7');
 let data8 = document.getElementById('data8');
 let data9 = document.getElementById('data9');
 let data10 = document.getElementById('data10');

    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(data => {
      data1.innerHTML = data[0];
      data2.innerHTML = data[1];
      data3.innerHTML = data[2];
      data4.innerHTML = data[3];
      data5.innerHTML = data[4];
      data6.innerHTML = data[5];
      data7.innerHTML = data[6];
      data8.innerHTML = data[7];
      data9.innerHTML = data[8];
      data10.innerHTML = data[9];
    })
  .setAutomatically();
  },1000 )
})
```

```css
#datatable {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

#datatable td, #data-table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#datatable tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#datatable tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#datatable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">  
        <tr>
            <th>Commercial Tasks</th>
            <th># of Pending Tasks</th>
            <th># Completed Tasks</th>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold" width="250">AMOUNT 1</td>          
            <td id="data1" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>  
            <td id="data6" style="text-align:center"></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold" >AMOUNT 2</td>
            <td id="data2" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>  
            <td id="data7" style="text-align:center"></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold" >AMOUNT 3</td>
            <td id="data3" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>  
            <td id="data8" style="text-align:center"></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold" >AMOUNT 4</td>
            <td id="data4" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>    
            <td id="data9" style="text-align:center"></td>             
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold" >AMOUNT 5</td>
            <td id="data5" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td> 
            <td id="data10" style="text-align:center"></td>                 
        </tr>
      </table>
```

What I want is when the spreadsheet is updated and the "TD" value changes from 0 to 1 the font color or background will change to red (Only for column "# of Pending Tasks") and when the spreadsheet is updated again and the "TD" value changes from 1 to 0 the font or background color will change to white. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an [if/else](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) statement. Since the data isn't loaded in properly, I can only guess how to get the value of the data. You would need a set of data from before the change and the data from the new and compare the two. The best would be if you use Arrays to store all the data, and not have so many variables hardcoded.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const dataCount = 10;
    const oldDataArray = [];
    const newDataArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
      const data = document.getElementById(`data${i}`);
      oldDataArray.push(data);
    }

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler((data) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < newDataArray.length; i++) {
          const newData = newDataArray[i];

          // if from 0 to 1
          if (oldDataArray[i].value === 0 && newData.value === 1) {
            newData.classList.add('colorRed');
          // if from 1 to 0
          } else if (oldDataArray[i].value === 1 && newData.value === 0) {
            newData.classList.remove('colorRed');
          }
        }
      })
      .setAutomatically();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.colorRed {
  color: red;
}

#datatable {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

#datatable td, #data-table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#datatable tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#datatable tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#datatable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">  
        <tr>
            <th>Commercial Tasks</th>
            <th># of Pending Tasks</th>
            <th># Completed Tasks</th>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold" width="250">AMOUNT 1</td>          
            <td id="data1" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>  
            <td id="data6" style="text-align:center"></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold" >AMOUNT 2</td>
            <td id="data2" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>  
            <td id="data7" style="text-align:center"></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold" >AMOUNT 3</td>
            <td id="data3" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>  
            <td id="data8" style="text-align:center"></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold" >AMOUNT 4</td>
            <td id="data4" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>    
            <td id="data9" style="text-align:center"></td>             
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold" >AMOUNT 5</td>
            <td id="data5" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td> 
            <td id="data10" style="text-align:center"></td>                 
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: I've tried to paste it on my script. Unfortunately, it's not working. This the code on my Code.gs "function setAutomatically(){
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  let val2 = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  let val3 = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  let val4 = sheet.getRange('B4').getValue();
  let val5 = sheet.getRange('B5').getValue();
  return [val2, val3, val4, val5];
}"